# C# Dynamically create JSON with nested objects from array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

So I have adynamic array of strings like:

```
["a","b","c,"d"]
```

or

```
["x","y","z"]
```

The array is dynamic and can have variable number of strings.

I want to create a nested json object, in the same position order of the items.

End result would be:

```
{
   "a":{
      "b":{
         "c":{
            "d":{
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

or

```
{
   "x":{
      "y":{
         "z":{
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what return type do you expect? String? Dictionary? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compose `JObject` to obtain what you want:

```
var strs = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

JObject jo = new JObject();
JObject parent = jo;

for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
{
    var jo2 = new JObject();
    parent[strs[i]] = jo2;
    parent = jo2;
}

// Your final json object is jo
Console.WriteLine(jo);

// string version
string json = jo.ToString(); // or jo.ToString(Formatting.None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works like a charm. can you explain how "jo2" has the same reference (it seems like that) as "parent" ?

Comment: @user2653271 No, `jo2` is always a reference to the innermost created object. `jo` is the most external parent, and `parent` is the previous parent.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance.. I just don't understand how jo2 gets the reference for the innermost object if jo2 is on the right side of the equal sign? 
in lines:
```var jo2 = new JObject();
parent[strs[i]] = jo2;```
I can see in debug what you explained, but still, i don't get it...

Comment: @user2653271 In the cycle you are creating objects for outside to inside. `jo2` is the current object you are creating, and you are adding it to its parent. By this definition, in each cycle jo2 is the innermost object you created.

Comment: In the first iteration, after the line `parent[strs[i]] = jo2;` the values of both `parent[strs[i]]` and `jo2` is:
`{"Module": {}}`
I expected jo2 to remain new JObject...

Comment: Don't know what you are looking at, or if you modified the code, but the current `jo2` is always a `{}`